# Server 2008 Port CNAME

Tags: windows-server-2008, cname-record

Server 2008
IIS 7

I have a server being utilized for 2 internal websites. The site on Port 80 is working fine, but I want to setup Port 81 as well, but unable to get this. I created a CNAME for Port 81 but did not work. I thought about a SRV but not sure about this.

Sites
site (works fine internally)
site:81 (want to setup for internal use to type INFO in address bar).

Please let me know of any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run both websites on the same Port 80; and assign Host Headers to each for the website you want them to serve.

So if you have website1 and website2 are CNAMEs for server01; then in the host headers (in the bindings section in the IIS manager) you would set them to website1 and website2 respectively.

[Here's a bit of an old Microsoft KB on how to do it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190008); the basics are the same in just about every version of IIS though.

Answer (score 0):

CNAMEs do not support port information, it has nothing to do with port information. You can either setup a CNAME that refers to a DNS service what will perform a web redirect (check to ensure that they do support port naming) or as Chris has detailed - a separate virtual host definition with the root page performing the web redirect with the port information.